# SAXNotRecognizedException while using gdata api's for youtube integrating in android?

Tags: android, youtube-api, gdata, saxparser

I am integrating youtube in my android app. I am using gdata youtube library for the same.

`

```
    YouTubeManager ym = new YouTubeManager(clientID);

    List<YoutubeVideo> videos;
    try {
        videos = ym.retrieveVideos(textQuery, maxResults, filter, timeout);
        for (YoutubeVideo youtubeVideo : videos) {
            System.out.println(youtubeVideo.getWebPlayerUrl());
            System.out.println("Thumbnails");
            for (String thumbnail : youtubeVideo.getThumbnails()) {
                System.out.println("\t" + thumbnail);
            }
            System.out.println(youtubeVideo.getEmbeddedWebPlayerUrl());
            System.out.println("************************************");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   `
```

I have imported jar's as under,
activation.jar
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-media-1.0.jar
gdata-youtube-2.0.jar
google-collect-1.0-rc2.jar
httpmime-4.0.3.jar
mail.jar
servlet.jar

Now I am getting an exception SAXNotRecognizedException at

> videos = ym.retrieveVideos(textQuery, maxResults, filter, timeout);

plz can any one tell me what is happening wrong over here. How to fix this error? Or any other way to integrate youtube in android app.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is reported as Issue 9493.

> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9493

And a workaround for it can be found here:

> http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.com/2011/11/solution-for-gdata-java-clients.html

SecureGenericXMLFactory in gdata-core intentionally disables some features, but some of them are needed to retrieve data from YouTube. The basic idea of the work around is as follows.

(1) Remove the original SecureGenericXMLFactory from gdata-core-1.0.jar

```
cd gdata-src.java-1.46.0/gdata/java/lib
mkdir gdata-core-1.0-no-SecureGenericXMLFactory
cd gdata-core-1.0-no-SecureGenericXMLFactory
jar xf ../gdata-core-1.0.jar
rm -rf com/google/gdata/util/common/xml/parsing
jar cfm ../gdata-core-1.0-no-SecureGenericXMLFactory.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF com
```

(2) Replace the original gdata-core-1.0.jar with the new one created by the step (1). (in Eclipse)

(3) Copy the original source code of SecureGenericXMLFactory to your Android project.

(4) Add an unconditional 'return' in the constructor of SecureSAXParserFactory before the code lines that disable the necessary features.

```
// "if (true)" was added to avoid a compilation error in Eclipse.
if (true)
{
    return;
}
```